# using callback for ie8 in video-js video.js

Tags: jwplayer, video.js

I am using this snippet to play videos with videojs. Fine in Firefox and Chrome. The callback to flash for ie8 is supposed to be JWPlayer, as recommended in video-js's web.

```
<video controls="controls" poster="./media/pic112.jpg" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="./media/Anyos.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="./media/Anyos.ogg" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="./media/Anyos.ogg" type="video/ogg" /> 
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="./jwplayer/player.swf" width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="./jwplayer/player.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=true&amp;controlbar=over&amp;image=./media/pic112.jpg&amp;file=./media/Anyos.mp4" />
        <!-- fallback image -->
        <img src="./media/pic112.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="Big Buck Bunny"
            title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
```

But I am doing something wrong. I see the JWPlayer, and a warning: `video not found or access denied`.

I used JWPlayer 5 (just the swf file), because using 6 gives another error "Offline playback not supported"

The behavior is the same in my computer (XP) or publishing the web through my host provider.

Comment: Are you mixing Video.js and JWPlayer for a particular reason? Both Video.js and JWPlayer offer a flash fallback.